# How to create browserify transform with support for source maps?

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, source-maps

I create library for JavaScript DOM templating - [Monkberry](https://github.com/monkberry/monkberry). Now it's support source map via Mozilla's [source-map](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map) lib.

I want to create browserify transform which will be support source maps.

How to do it?